# How to join two tables for particular column without using joins

Tags: sql, database

I am running a query on two different tables:-

```
select * from MessagesTable INNER JOIN ErrorTable ON MessagesTable.msgId = ErrorTable.msgId.
```

Is there an another way to write this query without using JOIN?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? And no there is no other way to join two tables other then to join them. Even if you don't use an explicit `JOIN` you are still joining them.

Comment: I just dont want to use JOIN but yes I do need to join them, so I am just asking the query I f its possible to join two tables dat without using JOIN?

Comment: What is wrong with  using an explicit `JOIN`? It's the best way to join two tables.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question stating the reason for what you are looking for to avoid further down votes from people.

Answer (score 1):

If you would not use join in query you can write sub query for this.

Below query for SQL DATABASE-

```
select * 
from MessagesTable 
where MessagesTable.msgId in (select ErrorTable.msgId from ErrorTable)
```

Comment: That's not a join

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you want to do it but YES you can do it as long as you want data from only `MessagesTable`. Its called `sub query`.

```
select * from MessagesTable WHERE msgId IN (select  msgId from ErrorTable)
```

Comment: That's not a join

Comment: I know but I believe the person posted the Q is looking for such an answer. It's just that question was not phrased properly.

Comment: will this do a trick?;- select * from MessagesTable,ErrorTable where MessagesTable.msgId = ErrorTable.msgId

Comment: Still that's a join! Its just that you are not using the JOIN keyword. What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this query in place of join for particular column

select * from MessagesTable,ErrorTable where MessagesTable.msgId =ErrorTable.msgId

Comment: So will it fetch all columns from MessagesTable and all columns from ErrorTable only where  MessagesTable.msgId =ErrorTable.msgId